# How to access the VisionOS (Vision Pro) camera in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, visionos, visionos-simulator

As a new developer working on a VisionOS app needing camera and microphone access, I'm unsure about the permission rules. Can someone guide me on where to find the policies for accessing Vision Pro's cameras and mic? I hope it's just about getting user consent.

Your assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

See this WWDC 2023 session, at about the 9:45 timestamp, which describes camera/microphone discovery and access: https://developer.apple.com/wwdc23/10094?time=585

You can't get access to the forward-facing camera (the "back" camera on an iPad). If you request/gain access to the "front" camera, you'll get the user's Persona (if one exists).

You could create a HUD and overlay it on the user's pass-through camera display, but you won't be able to capture that in your app.